# Can't access the timestamp of remote file using WinSCP

Tags: timestamp, last-modified, winscp, winscp-net

I'm using the WinSCP .NET assembly to programmatically connect to a remote server and get the timestamp (or last update date) of a particular file. I have not been successful in finding a method call.

Answer (score 0):

To get a timestamp of a single file use the `LastWriteTime` property of the [`RemoteFileInfo`](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/library_remotefileinfo) class instance returned by the [`Session.GetFileInfo`](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/library_session_getfileinfo):

```cs
Console.WriteLine(session.GetFileInfo("/etc/passwd").LastWriteTime)
```

To get timestamps of all files in a directory, iterate the collection of the `RemoteFileInfo` instances returned by the [`Session.ListDirectory`](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/library_session_listdirectory):

```cs
foreach (RemoteFileInfo fileInfo in session.ListDirectory("/etc").Files)
{
    Console.WriteLine(fileInfo.LastWriteTime);
}
```